# isEqualToString get me wrong result

Tags: objective-c, string

Well this is my code:

```
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"Row %i at View: %@",indexPath.row, [delegate.my_condition objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
   if ([@"0" isEqualToString:[delegate.my_condition objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        NSLog(@"Store is closed");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"Store is open");
```

and in log I do see:

```
2012-08-29 22:33:59.434 MyApp[2593:c07] Row 0 at View: 0
2012-08-29 22:33:59.435 MyApp[2593:c07] Store is open
2012-08-29 22:33:59.437 MyApp[2593:c07] Row 1 at View: 0
2012-08-29 22:33:59.438 MyApp[2593:c07] Store is open
2012-08-29 22:33:59.440 MyApp[2593:c07] Row 2 at View: 0
2012-08-29 22:33:59.441 MyApp[2593:c07] Store is open
```

So I do see that value is 0 but I do not see the if clause but the else clause.

Why is that?

```
myCondition is NSMutableArray
```

This is how I add items to my NSMutableArray:

```
NSString *parsed=[res objectForKey:@"Data"];
    [delegate.my_condition addObject:parsed];
```

Comment: What type of objects are in myCondition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the values in `delegate.my_condition` are strings? Those look like they might be `NSNumber*`s. And of course an `NSNumber*` will never be equal to an `NSString*`.

You may want to try something like

```
if ([[delegate.my_condition objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Store is closed");
} // ...
```

instead, which assumes that the value is either an `NSNumber*` or an `NSString*` that represents a number.

Answer (score 3):

There's not enough information here to provide a definitive answer, but I see a few possibilities.

1. The object is a string with a trailing space. `"0"` is not equal to `"0 "`, but it would look the same in the logging output.
2. The object is actually an `NSNumber`, with a value of 0. It would still look the same in logging, but it would not be an equal object. Try checking the class of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Is your NSMutableArray returning strings? This may be happening because you are returning an NSNumber type instead of a string. In that case you may want to place stringValue at the end of the object to convert it to a string.

Answer (score -1):

Try flipping the condition, like this:

```
if ([[delegate.my_condition objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
```

or

```
NSString *_string = [delegate.my_condition objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([_string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
```

It might be having troubles with calling a function on a string like that

Comment: This is completely nonsensical. In fact, if the object in question is really an `NSNumber*` (as I suggested), then this will crash.